# underscorejs how to combine two arrays of objects?

Tags: underscore.js

I have two arrays, oldBalances and newBalances

```
var oldBalances =  [
  {name: 'vacation', value: '21'},
  {name: 'account', value: '200'},
]

var newBalances = [
  {name: 'vacation', value: '25'},
  {name: 'order', value: '15'}
]

var allBalances = []
```

I want the allBalances array to have all the balances combined, but if the balance name  in the old one is the same as the new one i want to take the new one

```
var allBalances = [
  {name: 'account', value: '200'},
  {name: 'vacation', value: '25'},
  {name: 'order', value: '15'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in this way:

```
let allBalances = [];

_([...newBalances, ...oldBalances]).each(balanceItem => {
    if (_(allBalances).where({name: balanceItem.name).length) {
        // skip adding key that is added already
        continue;
    }
    allBalances.push(balanceItem);
});
```